# Multi-level access with ManyToMany relationships in Django

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have models, objects from which can be represented as a directed graph:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Record(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    content = models.TextField()
    sequels = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, through='Extend', related_name='extending')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Extend(models.Model):
    ancestor = models.ForeignKey(Record, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    descendant = models.ForeignKey(Record, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_unique_relationships",
                fields=["ancestor", "descendant"],
            ),
            models.CheckConstraint(
                name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_prevent_self_extend",
                check=~models.Q(ancestor=models.F("descendant")),
            ),
        ]
```

Anytime a new instance of `Record` is created and it has a relationship with another instance through the `Extend` model, I would love to calculate `author.user.userprofile.income` attribute in the `User` instance. The problem is I don't know how to calculate this attribute for all the ancestors of the newly created `Record` which follows some rule: if the newly created `Record` costs 50, the first-level ancestor gets 25 and 25 goes to other ancestors, constanly being divided by 2.

[image]

I can write the formula for the first-level ancestor, but what for others?

```
# In case of some purchase:
class ExtendPurchase(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Record)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    cost = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def calculate_income(self):
        for item in self.items.all():
            item.author.userprofile.income += self.cost / len(self.items.all()) / 2 # first-level; if one would like to extend more than one Record instance
            for ancestor in item.extending.all():
                ancestor.author.userprofile.income += self.cost / delimiter # I don't know what delimiter is to be written
        self.items.save()
```

Comment: You probably want to efficiently retrieve all the parents using eg https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: With _django-treebeard_, I can't see the implementation of inheritance from two or more parents.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to loop through the records recursively, and divide by 2 the cost in each loop.

Can this work for you?

```py
class ExtendPurchase(models.Model):
    # ...

    def calculate_income(self):

        def __income_from_record(record, cost):
            tmp_income = cost
            for rel in Extend.objects.select_related('descendant').filter(ancestor=record):
                tmp_income += __income_from_record(rel.descendant, cost/2)
            return tmp_income

        for record in self.items.all():
            income = __income_from_record(record, self.cost)
            record.ancestor.author.userprofile.income  = income
            record.ancestor.author.userprofile.save()
```

Comment: `Record` object has no attribute `ancestor`. Though I can access all ancestors with `for ancestor in record.extending.all()`

Comment: @PavelShlepnev, It can be `record.author.userprofile.